# Are moment generating functions still multiplicative if their random variables are not independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, actuarial-science

Given $X$ is a random variable with moment generating function $M(t)$, I am suppose to determine whether $M(t)M(5t)$ is the MGF of some random variable. The solution in my textbook says it is, if I let $Y=5X$ then $M(5t)$ is the MGF for $Y$ and thus $M(t)M(5t)$ is the MGF for $X+Y$, since moment generating functions are multiplicative.

But I looked up the proof that the MGF of $X+Y$ is the product of the MGF of $X$ and the MGF of $Y$, and it seems to follow from the independence of $X$ and $Y$. Here it is:

$$M_{X+Y}(t) = E[e^{(X+Y)t}] = E[e^{tX}e^{tY}].$$ Recall that $$E[g_1(X)g_2(Y)] = E[g_1(X)]E[g_2(Y)] \therefore E[e^{tX}e^{tY}] = E[e^{tX}]E[e^{tY}] = M_X(t)M_Y(t)$$

The step after "Recall that" relies on indendence of $X$ and $Y$. So in my problem, where $Y=5X$, this proof does not hold and thus I need another reason to believe that I can multiply these MGFs together. Thanks!

Comment: Well, $X+Y=6X$ in your case, so it has MGF $M(6t)$, so the statement is only true if, for some other reason, $M(6t)=M(5t)M(t)$.

Comment: It does ask if $M(5t)M(t)$ is the MGF for "some" random variable, so I suppose if I can find any r.v. that satisfies the property that $M(6t) = M(5t)M(t)$ then I have my solution. Is there an easy way I could go about finding such an r.v., or alternatively a way I can prove none exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the argument given is incorrect since $X + Y = 6X$ and so unless $M(5t)M(t) = M(6t)$ for every $t$ we will not have that the mgf of $X+Y$ is $M(t)M(5t)$.

However, it is always possible (and I think what is intended in the argument you mentioned) to take some probability space with random variables $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$ defined on it such that $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$ are independent and such that $X \stackrel{d}{=} \tilde{X}$ and $Y \stackrel{d}{=} 5X$. This then gives the result since the mgf of a random variable is determined by its distribution and, as you noted, the mgf of a sum of independent random variables is the product of their mgfs.

Comment: I am not familiar with any of this probability space or $X \stackrel{d}{=} \tilde{X}$ stuff. Do you think that the solution in my textbook is an error or is this something I should learn now? For context, I'm studying for the actuary P exam, in case that changes things

Comment: The solution in your textbook is wrong. For example, if $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$ then its mgf is $M_X(t) = e^{\frac12 t^2}$ so that $M_X(t)M_X(5t) = e^{\frac12 26t^2}$ which is the mgf of a mean $0$, variance $26$ random variable. However, if $Y = 5X$ then $X + Y = 6X$ which is a mean $0$, variance $36$ normal R.V. so that $ M_{X+Y}(t) = e^{\frac12 36 t^2}$ so that the proof given in the textbook is wrong here.

Comment: $A \stackrel{d}{=} B$ just means that $A$ and $B$ are random variables which are equal in distribution (which is iff $M_A(t) = M_B(t)$ if both mgfs exist). The key point of my answer is that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (not necessarily independent), you can always find random variables $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ such that $\tilde{X} \stackrel{d}{=} X$, $\tilde{Y} \stackrel{d}{=} Y$ and $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}$ are independent. Then you have that $M_{\tilde{X} + \tilde{Y}} = M_{\tilde{X}}M_{\tilde{Y}} = M_X M_Y$ which lets you fix the proof in your textbook (so the result is true)

Comment: @robert909 In plain English here is the argument intended in the book. Let $X$ and $Y$ be **independent** random variables, and impose the condition that $Y$ has the same _distribution_ as $5X$. Let $M(t)$ be the mgf of $X$. Then the mgf of $X+Y$ equals $M(t)M(5t)$.